# Using conditions to dynamically exclude POJO property in Jackson json serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, pojo

I have a requirement to dynamically exclude certain property within a List of a defined POJO.
The main POJO to be serialized is:

```
public class Foo
{
    List<Bar> bar;

    public void setBar(List<Bar> bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public List<Bar> getBar()
    {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public static class Bar
    {
        private int id;
        private boolean ignoreId;
        private String name;

        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setIgnoreId(boolean ignoreId)
        {
            this.ignoreId = ignoreId;
        }

        public boolean isIgnoreId()
        {
            return this.ignoreId;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

id is to be ignored if ignoreId = true, like so:

```
[
    { "id": "1", "name": "one" },
    { "name": "two" }
    { "name": "three" }
    { "id": "4", "name": "four" }
]
```

At the moment, I have tried using `JsonFilter` and `JacksonJsonViews` but couldn't get the required output.
I would be glad if any pointer can be given towards achieving this.

Comment: JsonFilter should be used in this case. Could you describe why filters did not work for you?

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov, I created a logic like so: 

`@JsonFilter("Exclude.Id")
class PropertyFilterMixIn {}`

If I have `Set<String> ignorableFieldNames = new ArrayList<String>().add("id");`
I can do:

`FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("Exclude.Id", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames));

ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);

System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(new Foo()));


my challenge's to dynamically add `id` to the `ignorableFieldNames[]` if & only if the `ignoreId` is true

Answer (score 2):

You should write a custom [Jackson filter](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html) which would filter out a POJO property depending on other property value. You should override the `PropertyFilter.serializeAsField()` method to get access to the instance of the serialized object. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonFilter2 {
    @JsonFilter("filter")
    public static class Bar {
        public final int id;
        @JsonIgnore
        public final boolean ignoreId;
        public final String name;

        public Bar(int id, boolean ignoreId, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.ignoreId = ignoreId;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static class ExcludeIdFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

        @Override
        protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void serializeAsField(Object pojo,
                                     JsonGenerator jgen,
                                     SerializerProvider provider,
                                     PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
            if (pojo instanceof Bar
                    && "id".equals(writer.getName())
                    && ((Bar) pojo).ignoreId) {
               writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            } else {
                super.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider, writer);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Bar> bars = Arrays.asList(new Bar(1, false, "one"),  new Bar(2, true, "two"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setFilters(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter", new ExcludeIdFilter()));
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(bars));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "one"
}, {
  "name" : "two"
} ]
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I seem to be getting `No filter configured with id...`

Comment: @Damilola the example above works for me. Which Jackson version are you on? Can you update your question with your filter code?

Comment: it looks like my issue is similar to the discussion with Tatu [here](http://markmail.org/message/ffhut2sigegulhkx#query:+page:1+mid:dygkifj7tv72bypx+state:results)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jackson 2.4.2.

Model object is:

```
public class PostProject
{
    /* The field template of this project */
    private List< FieldTemplateObject > field_templates;

    /**
     * @author Damilola Okuboyejo
     */
    @JsonFilter( "FieldTemplateIdFilter" )
    public static class FieldTemplateObject
    {
      private int     id;
      private boolean is_inherited;
      private String  item_type;

      /**
       * @return the id
       */
      public int getId()
      {
         return id;
      }

      /**
       * @param id
       *           the id to set
       */
      public void setId( int id )
      {
         this.id = id;
      }

      /**
       * @return the is_inherited
       */
      public boolean isIs_inherited()
      {
         return is_inherited;
      }

      /**
       * @param is_inherited
       *           the is_inherited to set
       */
      public void setIs_inherited( boolean is_inherited )
      {
         this.is_inherited = is_inherited;
      }

      /**
       * @return the item_type
       */
      public String getItem_type()
      {
         if( item_type == null )
         {
            item_type = PostProject.item_type;
         }
         return item_type;
      }

      /**
       * @param item_type
       *           the item_type to set
       */
      public void setItem_type( String item_type )
      {
         this.item_type = item_type;
      }
   }
}
```

Myy serializer is like so:

```
public static class ModelFieldSerializer extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
{
  @Override
  protected boolean include( BeanPropertyWriter writer )
  {
     return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean include( PropertyWriter writer )
  {
     return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void serializeAsField( Object pPojo, JsonGenerator pJgen,
        SerializerProvider pProvider, PropertyWriter pWriter )
        throws Exception
  {
     if( pPojo instanceof FieldTemplateObject )
     {
        if( ("id".equals( pWriter.getName() ))
              && ((FieldTemplateObject) pPojo).isIs_inherited() )
        {
           pWriter.serializeAsOmittedField( pPojo, pJgen, pProvider );
        }
        else
        {
           super.serializeAsField( pPojo, pJgen, pProvider, pWriter );
        }
     }
  }
}
```

NOTE: The model class is passed through the network in a client-server architecture env

Comment: Could you show how do you register your filter for the ObjectMapper? It is also make sense move the code into the question, since this is not actual answer.

Comment: `vJsonMapper.setFilters( new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(
                        "FieldTemplateIdFilter",
                        new ModelFieldSerializer() ) );`

Comment: are you using the ObjectMapper before or after setting filter? Can you make a complete class that reproduces your problem? Does the code from my answer work for you?

Comment: It's quite a verbose code. The comment I specify earlier in the answer section should reproduce the problem. I noticed as soon as I mark the `FieldTemplateObject` with  `@JsonFilter("FieldTemplateIdFilter" )`, I get the exception. As per jackson doc 2.3+, I noticed the property or the getter can also be annotated with @JsonFilter. If I try that, the problem goes away but no filtering occures.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the culprit.
Thanks a lot @Alexey for staying with me on this. After much try, I discover Jackson 2.4.2 might have required that I place my serialzer within the model it would work with. I wonder why though, but probably due to Java object serialization requirements, Jackson was failing to map the Filter at runtime. I hope Tatu would note this in Jackson documentation

```
public class PostProject
{
    /* The field template of this project */
    private List< FieldTemplateObject > field_templates;

    /**
     * @author Damilola Okuboyejo
     */
    @JsonFilter( "FieldTemplateIdFilter" )
    public static class FieldTemplateObject
    {
      private int     id;
      private boolean is_inherited;
      private String  item_type;

      /**
       * @return the id
       */
      public int getId()
      {
         return id;
      }

      /**
       * @param id
       *           the id to set
       */
      public void setId( int id )
      {
         this.id = id;
      }

      /**
       * @return the is_inherited
       */
      public boolean isIs_inherited()
      {
         return is_inherited;
      }

      /**
       * @param is_inherited
       *           the is_inherited to set
       */
      public void setIs_inherited( boolean is_inherited )
      {
         this.is_inherited = is_inherited;
      }

      /**
       * @return the item_type
       */
      public String getItem_type()
      {          
         return item_type;
      }

      /**
       * @param item_type
       *           the item_type to set
       */
      public void setItem_type( String item_type )
      {
         this.item_type = item_type;
      }
   }

   public static class ModelFieldSerializer extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
   {
      @Override
      protected boolean include( BeanPropertyWriter writer )
      {
         return true;
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean include( PropertyWriter writer )
      {
         return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void serializeAsField( Object pPojo, JsonGenerator pJgen,
            SerializerProvider pProvider, PropertyWriter pWriter )
            throws Exception
      {
         if( pPojo instanceof FieldTemplateObject )
         {
             boolean vAllowId = ((FieldTemplateObject) pPojo).isIs_inherited();
             if( !vAllowId && ("id".equals( pWriter.getName() )) )
             {
               return; // skip the id property
             }
             else
             {
               super.serializeAsField( pPojo, pJgen, pProvider, pWriter );
             }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Java object serialisation requirements do not apply to Jackson. You should have encountered something else. If you can post minimised reproducible sample code to GitHub, I try to  following up on this, otherwise I don't have a clue.

Comment: @Alexey I just posted a minified reproducible version to [GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/532)