# How to not include composed object into json?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following classes:

```
public class Container{
    String description;
    Element1 element1;
    Element2 element2;
}

public class Element1{
    String f11;
    String f12;
}

public class Element2{
    String f21;
    String f22;
}
```

I serialize `Container` to json format. For json serialization I use Jackson.

Now I want don't include `element1` and `element2` into json if `f11`, `f12` and `f21`, `f22` respectevily is blank.

As I understan I should write cistom serializer but I don't understand for which entity. `Element` or `Container` ? and how ?

P.S.

My question is not duplicate of [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

At this topic explains how to ignore null value inside Container. My question about how to ignore object inside Container which has only null values inside

Comment: This might help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603581/using-conditions-to-dynamically-exclude-pojo-property-in-jackson-json-serializat).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson serialization: ignore empty values (or null)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null)

Comment: @Raman Shrivastava please read update. My question is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An additional idea inspired by [StaxMan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013639/1756430) is to implement an "empty element module" that encapsulates all of the overrides to `isEmpty` for the different elements in the `Container`. For example the module could look something like this:

```
public class EmptyElementModule extends SimpleModule {
    private static final String NAME = "EmptyElementModule";

    public EmptyElementModule() {
        super(NAME);
        setSerializerModifier(new EmptyElementSerializerModifier());
    }

    public static class EmptyElementSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
        @Override
        public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
            Class<?> beanClass = beanDesc.getBeanClass();
            if (beanClass == Element1.class) {
                return new EmptyElement1Serializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
            } else if (beanClass == Element2.class) {
                // return element 2 serializer
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }

    public static class EmptyElement1Serializer extends JsonSerializer<Element1> {
        private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

        public EmptyElement1Serializer(JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer) {
            this.defaultSerializer = checkNotNull(defaultSerializer);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Element1 value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            defaultSerializer.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, Element1 value) {
            return value.f11 == null && value.f12 == null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you probably do need a custom serializer, the method that you need to override there is `isEmpty(...)`; and then specify inclusion strategy for property like so:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

This will let the "owning" object determine that serialization is to be avoided: otherwise custom serializer will be called and it MUST write a value -- you could write `null` of course, but custom serializer itself cannot just decline to write anything because property name has already been written by caller.

Comment: please provide a bit more details

Comment: Was not aware of the isEmpty(...) method. That is a much cleaner solution compared to redefining serialize(...).

Comment: When I extends from **JsonSerializer**  I should override **serialize** method because it  abstract

Comment: Please advise which class should I extend to override only **isEmpty** method

Comment: I think a down side to this approach is that you would need to define a custom serializer for every element type. The OP mentioned in a comment that they have 10+ element types in this container. I think regardless you are writing config specific for each element unless they happen to all extend a common base.

Comment: I added an answer here that I think is along the lines of what StaxMan is recommending (with the addition of `@JsonInclude` to your container for this example): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31034525/1756430

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, you also have to implement actual serialization, not just isEmpty().

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the elements in the container that have only null/empty members (the container's members, members) you can create a custom serializer for `Container`. Custom serializers are great because they give you ultimate control of how an object is written, but this can also lead to code that is difficult to maintain. I say this because with Jackson you can accomplish practically anything with a custom de/serializer, but there is usually a cleaner way (through annotations for example) for most problems. For this, the OP requested guidance on writing a custom serializer, and I don't know a simpler way to accomplish the desired behavior.

### Create a `Module` and Custom Serializer

A Jackson `Module` is used to encapsulate a deserializer and serializer for a single object. For this example only a serializer is needed, but if you wanted to add a deserializer for `Container` you could just add it alongside the serializer inside of `ContainerModule`. The following code defines a serializer for `Container` that will only write `element1` and `element2` if at least one of their members are non-null:

```
public class ContainerModule extends SimpleModule {
    private static final String NAME = "ContainerModule";

    public ContainerModule() {
        super(NAME);
        addSerializer(Container.class, new ContainerSerializer());
    }

    public static class ContainerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Container> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Container container, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            if (container != null) {
                // start object and write description
                jg.writeStartObject();
                jg.writeStringField("description", container.description);

                // only write Element1 if one of its members exist
                Element1 element1 = container.element1;
                if (element1 != null) {
                    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(element1.f11)
                            && !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(element1.f12)) {
                        jg.writeFieldName("element1");
                        jg.writeObject(element1);
                    }
                }

                // only write Element2 if one of its members exist
                Element2 element2 = container.element2;
                if (element2 != null) {
                    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(element2.f21)
                            && !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(element2.f22)) {
                        jg.writeFieldName("element2");
                        jg.writeObject(element2);
                    }
                }

                // close the Container object
                jg.writeEndObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Register the Custom Serializer

The serializer can be registered globally on the `ObjectMapper` or on the class using `@JsonDeserialize`.

**`ObjectMapper` Registration**

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new ContainerModule());
```

**Class-level Registration**

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ContainerModule.ContainerSerializer.class)
public class Container {
    String description;
    Element1 element1;
    Element2 element2;
}
```

This should produce the following results:

```
// Full container
{
  "description" : "an awesome description",
  "element1" : {
    "f11" : "f11 value",
    "f12" : "f12 value"
  },
  "element2" : {
    "f21" : "f21 value",
    "f22" : "f22 value"
  }
}

// Null Element1 properties
{
  "description" : "an awesome description",
  "element2" : {
    "f21" : "f21 value",
    "f22" : "f22 value"
  }
}

// Null Element2 properties
{
  "description" : "an awesome description",
  "element1" : {
    "f11" : "f11 value",
    "f12" : "f12 value"
  }
}

// Null Element1 and 2 properties
{
  "description" : "an awesome description"
}
```

Comment: problem that I have 100+ String fields into Container and 10+ Elements and each element have 4..10 String fields.

Comment: @gstackoverflow see [StaxMan's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31013639/1756430). Defining isEmpty should be preferred over serialize(...) if possible.

Comment: Should I extend another class at this case?

Answer (score -1):

If you use annotations this should work fine:

```
public class Container{
    String description;
    @JsonIgnore
    Element1 element1;
    @JsonIgnore
    Element2 element2;
}
```

So Jackson ignores these two where @JsonIgnore is annotated

Comment: I need ignore element1 only when f11 and f12 is blank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null take a look

Comment: this topic relevant if element1 is null