# How to override isEmpty method of JsonSerializer for specific class without overriding serialize method?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I want to add custom behaviour for **isEmpty** method.

When I extends from `JsonSerializer<MySpecificClass>`

I should override serialize method because it abstract.

I want leave serialize method as is and override only isEmpty method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to modify the `isEmpty` behavior but maintain default serialization you can take advantage of a **serializer modifier**. You still have to implement a custom serializer, but you can utilize default serialization pretty cleanly.

### Create a custom serializer with the default serializer injected

Inject a `defaultSerializer` variable in to your custom serializer class. You will see where this serializer comes from when we implement the modifier. In this class you will override the `isEmpty` method to accomplish what you need. Below, if `MySpecificClass` has a null `id` it is considered empty by Jackson.

```
public class MySpecificClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MySpecificClass> {
    private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

    public MySpecificClassSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer) {
        this.defaultSerializer = checkNotNull(defaultSerializer);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(MySpecificClass value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        defaultSerializer.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, MySpecificClass value) {
        return value.id == null;
    }
}
```

### Create a custom `BeanSerializerModifier`

Extend `BeanSerializerModifier` and override the `modifySerializer` method. Inside of this method you can filter on the class type that you want to operate on, and return your custom serializer accordingly.

```
public class MyClassSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == MySpecificClass.class) {
            return new MySpecificClassSerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

### Register the modifier with the `ObjectMapper`

Registering the modifier will allow your serializer to trigger anytime the condition in `modifySerializer` is met.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                .setSerializerModifier(new MyClassSerializerModifier()));
```

Comment: method MySpecificClassSerializer#serialize invokes, but MySpecificClassSerializer#isEmpty - not

Comment: You likely need to specify an inclusion rule on your parent class: `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` or globally on the `ObjectMapper` using `setSerializationInclusion`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Please explain how to register several  SerializeModifiers ?

Comment: You can chain `registerModule`. You will need to instantiate a new module for each serializer modifier. You also could use a single modifier and check for your various classes using `BeanDescription#getBeanClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you anyway have to have an implementation for the serialize method, as it is abstract. You couldn't instantiate your class if at least one method is left abstract

Comment: If I don't write custom serializer default implementation uses.I want change it a bit

Comment: @gstackoverflow I had a look into org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer from jackson-mapper-asl 1.8.6 and I don't see there any "default implementation", only abstract definition.  Where do you see it?

Comment: I mean that if you don't write custom serializer, jackson anyway can convert your object into json format

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider