# Jackson - define empty fields without using JsonSerializer & BeanSerializerModifier

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a pojo with a lot of pojo fields in it, and I serialize them using Jackson.
For example:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class FOO {
    private BOO boo = new BOO();
    private GOO goo = new GOO();

    // Getters & setters
}
```

The inner class BOO is defined for example:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class BOO {
    private AAA aaa = new AAA();
    private BBB bbb = new BBB();

    // Getters & setters
}
```

Now, I would like the BOO class to be serialized to JSON only when all its fields (aaa,bbb in my example) are null or empty.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31034525/1028741), and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria), that I can do it using JsonSerializer & BeanSerializerModifier.

But, I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it, without defining an additional class for each custom field I want to handle.
For example, it would be nice if I could somehow override and implement a Jackson isEmpty() method for my BOO object (implementing some Jackson interface).

Is there such a simpler way to do it?

**EDIT:**

I would like to be able to do the following, without having to check for nulls:

```
foo.getBoo().getAaa();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with logic in the getter method:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class FOO {
    private BOO boo = new BOO();
    private GOO goo = new GOO();

    public BOO getBoo() {
        //replace if block with "empty" check logic
        if(this.boo.getAaa() == null || this.boo.getBbb() == null) {
            return this.boo;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Combined with the `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` instruction, the field will not be included when null.

Of course, as you mentioned, you can add `isEmpty()` to `BOO` and call it from the getter method.

Comment: While this could work, I would like to be able to call foo.getBoo().getAAA();
which will throw NPE in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the trick overriding the serialization of `boo` property with a `@JsonGetter` annotation. I simplified the models just for the sake of the example.

The simplified `FOO` class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class FOO {
    private BOO boo = new BOO();    

    @JsonGetter("boo")
    private BOO serializeEmptyBOO() {
        if (this.boo.isEmpty()) {
            return this.boo;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Getters & setters
}
```

The simplified `BOO` class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class BOO {    

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // Your isEmpty implementation
    }
}
```