# How to registrer custom jackson filter in spring application?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have read following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25609465/2674303

I have spring-mvc application. If I annotate controller method with `@ResponseBody` annotation and return object inside method, then server gives json to clients. I have Jackson in classpath.

In mentioned example wrote following code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilters(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter", new ExcludeIdFilter()));
```

As I understand this code already written somewhere in spring internals...

Please clarify how to register custom jackson filter ?

Comment: If you want the objects returned by your controllers to pass through your custom filter, you are going to have to extend `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and then register your new `HttpMessageConverter` in your servlet configuration. There are numerous questions on SO that have covered this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your own instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().json()
       .filters(new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter", new ExcludeIdFilter()));

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = 
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);

    // then replace the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    // with your custom one in the list of configured converters
  }

}
```

Comment: This is great, but it didn't work properly for me until I added @EnableWebMvc

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it via defined your mapping in `<mvc:message-converters>` Below example just used `StringHttpMessageConverter`  so it means all String fields are converted as json at your responseValueObjects, if you want your objects also convert to jSon you should write your custom message convertor and set it at  `<mvc:message-converters>`.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Activate to Spring MVC annotion like @RequestMapping or @Controller -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Assume you query your users, below is the Controller class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "api/queryUser")
public class ApiQueryUser {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ValidationService validationService;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public UserResponseValue queryUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
            UserResponseValue userResponseValue = new UserResponseValue();
            String userName = request.getParameter("USERNAME");
            String password = request.getParameter("PASSWORD");
            String email = request.getParameter("EMAIL");
            try {
                // validationService.validateParamaterNotNull(userName, password);
                BR_User user = userService.queryUser(userName, password, email);
                userResponseValue.setUserName(user.getUserName());
                userResponseValue.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                userResponseValue.setRole(user.getRole());
                userResponseValue.setResponseCode("100");
                userResponseValue.setResponseMessage("User exist");
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                userResponseValue.setResponseCode("99");
                userResponseValue.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode().name());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                userResponseValue.setResponseCode("98");
                userResponseValue.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode().name());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                userResponseValue.setResponseCode("96");
                userResponseValue.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.ERR20000.name());
            }
            return userResponseValue;
        }
    }
```

finally responseValue object, take care that all the fileds are `String`

```
public class UserResponseValue{
    private String userName;
    private String role;
    private String email;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

and be sure Jackson dependency is added at your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- To use responseBody as a default JSON messageConverter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is working example from my project. I am using Spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have found temporary this solution :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonFilterAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<List<?>>
{

   @Override
   public List<?> beforeBodyWrite(
      List<?> arg0,
      MethodParameter arg1,
      MediaType arg2,
      Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> arg3,
      ServerHttpRequest arg4,
      ServerHttpResponse arg5)
   {
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) arg4).getServletRequest();
      String[] params = servletRequest.getParameterValues("filters");
      if (params != null)
      {
        // parse object and set field to null
      }
      return arg0;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean supports(MethodParameter arg0, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> arg1)
   {
      // return true if method parameters contain 'filters' field
      return true;
   }
```

any other suggestions are welcome